How to quickly deselect loose parts in edit mode? Similar to ctrl double clicking a face in maya
I already know workarounds(select linked then invert) in some cases but they're not applicable everytime. I'm looking for a similar quick function like in maya so I can deselect the faces of the unconnected faces in an object.



Hello and welcome. Have you tried hovering over the area you want to deselect and pressing L key and then ticking the Deselect checkbox like shown here https://imgur.com/a/2fV6PqK

Thanks. It was actually Shift+L that I was looking for.

Oh yeah that's the shorter shortcut. Glad you found a suitable solution :)

Hover over the region you want to deselect and press Shift+L.
